# How to merge dataframe column values having duplicate values and other with different one's?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have a df with values

```
    0     |   1
15sdttb   |  sun 
wnx526y   |  earth
15sdttb   |  mercury
wnx526y   |  moon
15sdttb   |  mars
15sdttb   |  jupyter
```

how to merge the two same values in df by combining with all different values in 1

And second output should be talking the first two preferences

1. output should be

   ```
        0     |   1
    15sdttb   |  sun/mercury/mars/jupyter
    wnx526y   |  earth/moon
   ```
2. output (taking first two preferences)

   ```
        0     |   1
    15sdttb   |  sun/mercury
    wnx526y   |  earth/moon
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x))
df.reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
            A                                  B
0  15sdttb       sun /  mercury/  mars/  jupyter
1  wnx526y                          earth/  moon
```

For first two preferences

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x[:2]))
df.reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
            A                 B
0  15sdttb       sun /  mercury
1  wnx526y         earth/  moon
```

Comment: Worked !!! But B column disappeared and output is not in df.

Comment: ya just do a reset index..i'll update

Comment: please also look into the dupe link, will help

Comment: sure . looking into that